# how to make a symbol come in the middle of the screen even if the viewer resizes it in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a simple symbol

```
var button:graphic = new graphic();
    button.x=250;
    button.y=200;
    addChild(button);
```

I want this to come in middle :

```
var posX:number = stage.width/2
var posY:number = stage.height/2

button.x=posX
button.y=posY
```

This came into my mind ^ but when i run  it it shows the following errors:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: number. //for pos X
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: number. //for pos Y
```

I find this as the only solution but sadly this is not working
I may be writing those lines wrong as i am new to whole programming thing .

Please correct my solution or if it is wrong Please tell the right one

Comment: use Number instead of number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you are experiencing a case issue with the [`Number`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html) data type.

As well, you should reference `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight` properties.

```
var posX:Number = stage.stageWidth / 2;
var posY:Number = stage.stageHeight / 2;
```

You may wish to compensate for the width and height of your symbol, as in:

```
var posX:Number = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (button.width / 2);
var posY:Number = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (button.height / 2);
```

Finally, listen for `Event.RESIZE` events to handle changes to stage size:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
import flash.display.StageAlign;

stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));

function resizeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var posX:Number = (stage.stageWidth / 2) - (button.width / 2);
    var posY:Number = (stage.stageHeight / 2) - (button.height / 2);

    button.x = posX;
    button.y = posY;
}
```

As an example, here is [Adobe Flash CS5 FLA source code](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/symbol-position/symbol-position.fla), [HTML](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/symbol-position/symbol-position.html), and compiled [SWF](http://jasonsturges.com/labs/stack-overflow/examples/symbol-position/symbol-position.swf).

Comment: 1120: Access of undefined property resizeHandler.

Comment: Implement the function, as in the example.  Download the referenced FLA as an additional example.

Comment: My adobe cs3 says it has unexpected file formate it will be kind of you if you can post code(including function and class in it ) directly here so that i can see it

Comment: solved the problem and its working but now it passes an argument
i created function like function resizeHandler(){
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);
stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));
}

ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on main/::resizeHandler(). Expected 0, got 1.

Comment: Excellent - the function should be: `function resizeHandler(event:Event):void { /* code here */ }` - if you copy / paste the code above in a frame it should function as expected.  Sorry, I can't save back to CS3.